# How to execute adb commands programatically using Java

Tags: java, adb, appium

I need to execute the adb commands in my java program to perform certain actions in the Android app but unfortunately I didn't find a way to do that. How can I achieve this using Java. Is ProcessBuilder the only way to achieve this or do we have any other way to achieve this. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
          // for data access
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
          String data;
          while((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(data);
          }
          br.close();
          // do whatever you want with sb content        
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```